# Find all elements with matching indexes and get largest attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to dynamically set heights across all table headings based on the tallest corresponding div on its index. I will be using MaterializeCSS which responsively makes the headings display block and the content scroll right to left.

I'll use a super simple example.

```
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th>Heading 1</th>
  <th>Heading 2</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>This content is 100px</td> 
    <td>This content is 50px</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>This content is 50px</td>
    <td>This content is 200px</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

In the example I showed, I'd like to set the height of the `th` for heading 1 to 100px and the height of `th` for heading 2 to 200px.

I tried a few things and got completely lost. Maybe I was trying to get too cute with it. The logic I was attempting was:

- For each `th` in `thead`

  - Find `td` with same index as the `th` within each `tr` within `tbody` and get largest height
  - Set height of `th`

I get that it would start with `$('th').each(function () { //magic goes here });`

Here is a Codepen I have to show my progress on it: https://codepen.io/hdwebpros/pen/vjbwyw

Thanks in advance for any help or guidance. I appreciate it!

Comment: CSS is going to be a **much** better way of doing this. Also `th`s can't have different heights.. The table will just adjust to the highest.

Comment: But CSS would not be able to dynamically find the value it would need to use, right?

Comment: That logic makes no sense anyway @DanielApt

Comment: Agreed, setting different heights for a `th` inside the same `thead` would not even render nicely.

Comment: @liam I am using responsive table layouts via materialize where the th elements will stack up vertically (display block) and the content scrolls left to right.

Comment: Might of been useful to mention this? @hdwebpros...

Comment: I'm sorry, @liam I just clarified my post.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

- for each row `tr`

  - for each column `td`

    - compute the max height `h[c]` of every column with the same index
- assign the max height to each column with the same index

```js
var h = [];
$("#table tr").each(function(r, tr) {
  $(tr).find("td").each(function(c, td) {
    if (c == 0) {
      h.push($(td).height());
    } else {
      if ($(td).height() > h[c]) {
        h[c] = $(td).height();
      }
    }
  });
});
for (var c = 0; c < h.length; c++) {
  $("#table td:eq(" + c + ")").css("height", h[c]);
}
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <th>Heading 1</th>
    <th>Heading 2</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="height: 100px;">This content is 100px</td>
      <td style="height: 50px;">This content is 50px</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="height: 50px;">This content is 50px</td>
      <td style="height: 200px;">This content is 200px</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you. It's not exact, since I was trying to set the heights of the th element. But that was an easy fix. I never really used the `.push` and `eq:` so thank you for showing me that!

Comment: Shoot. When I tried your example with content and CSS added, the results aren't right. The heights don't seem to be calculating correctly. https://codepen.io/hdwebpros/pen/vjbwyw